# 'Event viewer log files save as XML' saves only 305 records

Tags: xml, windows, xpath, event-viewer

I have 1450 event logs in my event viewer.

When I filter it using dates, say from Aug 25 2014 to Aug 31 2014, it gets reduced to 774.
When I try to save the log files as XML by selecting the 'Save event file as' and then selecting XML as file type, it saves only the last 305 records.

When I save it as csv, I can see all 774 events saved.
When I try to save the complete list of 1450 as XML it saves all logs. The problem only occurs when a date filter is applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow. I thought I was crazy. I'm trying to export 8,000 events as CSV. When I open the CSV file, it only has 305 records. Did anyone solve this riddle?

Answer (score 7):

There's a funny workaround:

1. `Save All Events As...` and save to `.evtx`
2. Open saved file
3. `Save All Events As...` and save to `.csv` / `.xml` ...

([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9d7c210-399d-43e7-aaa9-4e02295b3a19/how-do-i-save-more-events-from-event-viewer-to-a-text-file?forum=w8itprogeneral#54788513-0695-4e87-b4c6-1146195e0deb)) At least, this works for me on Windows 10 x64 version 1709.

The issue itself is clearly a bug, you can vote for them to fix it on the Feedback Hub: [for normal users](https://aka.ms/G98d0a), [for insiders](https://aka.ms/Xzpzqn).

Comment: What a stupid bug! The suggested workaround worked pretty fine!

Comment: Bug still exists in May of 2020.  How embarrassing.  Workaround still works.

Comment: I only had 50 events when I saved an XPath filtered log.  When I followed the workaround, I got 305 events.  Better than before but not the 1225 events actually filtered.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the xml section in filter, we have something like

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=2) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 3600000]]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Basically this is the one applying the filter. can you check in those lines, whether your entries will be discarded if not?

Comment: Yes your are right, thats the one which applies to the filter, but there is nothing in the query which restricts the count of logs to be exported(when saving to xml)

Comment: Okay, in that case we will need to debug in steps. So can you post a small snippet of the full xml and the entry what you think is missing. we can try to figure out pattern on what is missing, like is it after 350 entries everything, anything of particular type and so on. I would use beyond compare on full and filtered xml to see what's missing first and identify a pattern.

Comment: i guess the issue can be reproduced, if you've got more than 350 event entries in your log, just filter them by date, say from day before yesterday to today, and this filter result should output more than 350 event records, then try to save it as xml